# Updating mobile version in android

Tags: android, css, cordova, mobile

I'm currently developing my first app with Visual Studio 2015 - Apache Cordova. I've coded everything and the code is fully working on my Ripple (emulator in browser) which has 4.x.x OS.

However, when i pack up the apk and move it to my phone (which has 6.x.x OS) it works normally, but the modals, bootstraps and stylesheets (CSS-file) are not working. To clarify; If I've made style modifications in my HTML-file, those changes will be shown how they should be, in the app.

Is there any way that I could change the pre-requisites so it works on my Phones current OS (6.x.x) or is there simpler method to work around this?